# Using as.Date creates NA R

Tags: r

Whenever I read in my table (its a .txt) and set the date column to actual dates, it just returns that column as all NAs. Here's what I'm running.

`columnH <- read.table("file.txt", header=FALSE, sep="")`

This works fine. Reads in the .txt file with ease and no formatting issues. The data I'm setting as date is :

```
("01-29-10", 
"01-29-93", "01-29-99", "01-30-04", "01-30-09", "01-30-15", "01-30-98", 
"01-31-00", "01-31-01", )
```

I chopped that down heavily.

Anyway, here's where it messes up.

```
columnH$V1 <- as.Date(columnH$V1, format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

This returns all those dates as `NA`. I've tried with different formats and no format (basically letting R do it itself) but I haven't had any luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the file separator in your data?  What is the one in the format?   Hence `NA`.   There are hundreds of prior questions on `as.Date()` here, please make use of the search box at the top right. Try `"[r] as.Date"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't it work with this formatting?

```
columnH$V1 <- as.Date(columnH$V1, format="%m-%d-%y")
```

Check if the dash is a special character instead of "-". In that case, you just need to change the encoding.

Comment: Sort of. For some reason they are printing out like this `0090-01-31`

Comment: Read. The. Documentation.  You need `%y` not `%Y`.

Comment: Oh true, the Y should be in lower case.

Comment: Okay, but still one question remains. If I have it as `"%m-%d-%y"` then why would it print out in `1990-01-31`. I'd assume it'd return the value in the order I formatted it in?

Comment: It returns a Date object storing separately day, month, and year. It displays it using the standard formatting ("%Y-%m-%d"), but you can still re-convert it into a character.